# How can I display background image in td, but not the text?

Tags: html, css

A CMS puts the website menu in a table.

I've edited this to be clearer ....

The 'input' HTML is not very helpful, it is: 
`<div id="hdr">#HMAINS#</div>`

The CMS replaces the #HMAINS# above with the menu, structured in a simple table with class-"hmains".

Page Source code looks like:
***HTML***
`<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="hmains">
     <tbody><tr>
     <td......></td>
    ...
     <td class="hmains"><a href="https://ss.smile-nz.com/~qenew1/" class="hmains">Logo</a></td>
    ...
    </table>`

I want to put a background image in one of the cells, and NOT display the text. i.e. replace the text link with an image link.

I can't directly change the td unless I go to JS, the table gets built by the CMS....

I was hoping there was some clever css that would allow me to suppress the text in that particular td?

The css below selects that td and adds the image

**CSS**

```
#hdr td:nth-child(5) {
    width: 50px;
    height: 76px;
    background-image: url(images/QE_Logo_edit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

In dev tools, the color shows as transparent in the expected td, but the 'Logo' text inserted by the plugin is still visible?

[image: snip of section of menu]

Comment: Is the 'Logo' text being inserted in another element with inline styles? What does the markup look like around the text you are trying hide?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to know the significance of `#hdr td:nth-child(5)` if there's no HTML? Please post the HTML and the CSS that would apply to said HTML. BTW your wasting both of our time if you don't provide more CSS thinking that what you've posted is sufficient. Refer to how to make a [mcve].

Comment: It's much better to put the image as a clickable <img> in the menu item, rather than a background image. In any case, you could use a browser code inspector to find the CSS rule to target and hide placeholder text being generated by a plugin.

Comment: you can increase z-index for image tag

Answer (score 0):

just insert the image using `<img src='...'>` tag inside the td

Answer (score 0):

Remove the text and simply add the image tag there as `<img src=''>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to any other pages or make an image clickable just add the img tag inside an a tag in your td

```
<td>
<a href="your link">
<img border="0" alt="alt_text" src="image_src" width="100" height="100">
</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some missed the point that an external source controls the table HTML, so I can't directly change the td tag.  I suspect one can't change the text inside a td through CSS, so just to put this to bed, in this case I did it in JS as follows (remembering there is a parent div id='hdr'):

```
            <script> /***  remove 'logo' text from menu **/
            document.getElementById('hdr').getElementsByTagName('td')[4].innerHTML = "";
        </script>
```

All in the learning curve :-)

Answer (score 0):

use an inline style in the **td** tag.

```
<td style="background-image:url(./demoImage.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:250px 180px;   width: 250px; height: 180px;"></td>
```